# Get type from Array<T>

Tags: typescript

I have an auto generated type,

```
export type ReferralListByCustomerQuery = { referralListByCustomer?: Array<{ code: string, referredByID: string } |  undefined> |  undefined };
```

But I need a type of Item of Array:

`type WhatINeed = { code: string, referredByID: string } |  undefined`

So, I know how to extract array type:

`type IncludingArray = ReferralListByCustomerQuery[referralListByCustomer]`

but question is how to extract Array Item. after google:

`type OnlyItem  = IncludingArray[number]` is not working

Answer (score 4):

This is the same as `T[number]`, but you can extract like this also:

```
type ElementOf<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never
```

You can then use it like this

```
type SomeArrayType = Array<{foo: string}>;
type TheTypeOfThoseElements = ElementOf<SomeArrayType>;
type SomeOtherType = ElementOf<typeof someVariable>;
```

You might also need to omit the `| undefined` from the type, which can be done like this:

```
type DefinitelyDefined<T> = Exclude<T, undefined>
```

Comment: this worked:

type ElementOf<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never

type ReferralListByCustomerQuery = { referralListByCustomer?: Array<{ code: string, referredByID: string } |  undefined> |  undefined };

type ReferralItemArray = ReferralListByCustomerQuery["referralListByCustomer"];
type TheTypeOfThoseElements = ElementOf<ReferralItemArray>

Still can't get why T[number] is not working. Can you give me the implementation of T[number] with the example I have?